# Can't Stop Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 2.2.2.   Did a build of my project and after several minutes I noticed that it still hadn't completed and at the bottom of my screen Android Studio said I had a process running.  When I clicked on it it said it was the Gradle Build so I clicked to stop it.   The display changed to

> Stopping - Gradle Build Running

But it never seems to stop.   If I restart the build that whole sequence repeats itself so now I have TWO

> Stopping - Gradle Build Running

dialogs.    But they never actually stop, even after 15+ minutes! If I try to shut down Android Studio it puts up an "Are You Sure?" dialog warning me I have background tasks running.

What's the right way to shut these down cleanly and how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You need to manually kill the gradle deamon instances, and then you can restart your android studio

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in a terminal:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

It kills all the gradle processes.

Comment: This doesn't work in this scenario, it hangs

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it happens, Due to many reasons like your system Ram or memory. Just try to close everything and restart it again. It happened with me somedays back. I did the same process and after this, it works fine in my system.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, it returned to normal only after restarting the machine.
Some of the cached temporary files seem to have caused the problem.